# Is there a list of Japanese characters that don't have equivalent roots in Chinese?

Tags: kanji, loanwords, chinese

According to [this answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/22712/6228):

> Almost all Japanese characters (in my experience >99%) are exist in Chinese. Few are changed a little, like 宮 and 宫. As a Chinese, I have no difficulty in recognizing Japanese characters.

Now, I wonder which character is what was invented in Japan, or maybe imported from Korea but not originally from China, if any.

Is there any research regarding this area or is there such compiled list?

Comment: @naruto Hmmm.... it's not a duplicate I think. The OP asks about the existance but I recognize it and am looking for a compiled list. Your answer there doesn't include a link to the list but a link to [a link to the possible answer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Japanese-only_CJKV_Characters), which claims 108 such characters, but the other answerer there has a link that claims 3,000+ such characters.

Comment: See Takeshi Sonn's answer, not mine.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of characters is called 国字 or 和製漢字. So through a search of these terms on the internet, you can find the [Wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%92%8C%E8%A3%BD%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97) the introduces these character, which also contains a simple list.

And on that Wikipedia page, there is also a link to [和製漢字の辞典2014](http://ksbookshelf.com/nozomu-oohara/WaseikanjiJiten/), which is an online dictionary for the Japanese made characters.